# How can i add AppBar in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: .net, mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In windows phone 8, its very easy to add an App Bar and manage it, but now i test new windows phone 8.1 SDK to build a project with new Geofencing feature but i don't know how to add an App Bar in the App.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, We can use `BottomAppBar` to add App Bar. Usually we use `CommandBar` to create basic BottomAppBar. CommandBar contains two collection: `PrimaryCommands` and `SecondaryCommands`, It's similar with `shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons` and `shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems` in Windows Phone 8.

Read this demo please, we create a CommandBar with two buttons: ZoomOut and ZoomIn, and two menuItem:Test01 and Test02 :

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsSticky="True" x:Name="appBar">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="ZoomOut" IsCompact="False" Label="ZoomOut"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="ZoomIn" IsCompact="False" Label="ZoomIn"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="Test01"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Test02"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Edit: Now the code is correct!

Comment: `IsSticky` doesn't do anything on WP 8.1

Comment: Is it possible to be placed on top of the app? (TopAppBar lets say)

Comment: We can't do that. In windows phone, there is BottomAppBar only.

Comment: Check out this link to add an app bar using XAML -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394040(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way. Scroll all the way to the top of the XAML afterwards, click on the first text/string `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage` you can either press F4 in order to bring up the "Common" selection or you can just click on it and just go to properties and press "Common" and there you will see a new option called "ApplicationBar". This way is much better, you can create a new fresh one this way.

Comment: It is also a good way if i can choose two answers as correct i will do thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Create Class with Method

```
public static void AddNewAppBarinPage(Page myPage)
{
   CommandBar cbar = new CommandBar { ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Minimal };
   AppBarButton appBarButton = new AppBarButton { Label = "Audio" };
   cbar.PrimaryCommands.Add(appBarButton);
   myPage.BottomAppBar = cbar;
}
```

use in Page:

```
AppBarCustom.AddNewAppBarinPage(this);
```