# I can't create an AppBar in windows phone 8.1 c#/Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, appbar

So i m trying to create a TopAppBar but so far I didn't managed to do it.

I tried this code but BottomAppBar is not found inside the Page type.
[How can i add AppBar in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529527/how-can-i-add-appbar-in-windows-phone-8-1)

I tried through Blend but the thing weird is that I have the AppBarButton control but not the AppBar control.

I dont know how to have the Appbar control.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using 8.1 Silverlight, or 8.1 Store App?

Comment: hi kai , im using 8.1 store app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your designer page (i.e Mainpage.xaml) find the page tag "" and in the properties window you can directly add appbar by clicking on new

**Remember** You can find this Bottom appbar only in page control

[image]